# Basic html layout question

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to build a page which will have a box-like layout..A top banner a bottom banner,two navigation panels(left and right) and some text that will appear in the middle.

Now I'm wondering if you can create something like that without using a table and without predefined/hardcoded values for margins.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Mike

Comment: http://www.noupe.com/css/9-timeless-3-column-layout-techniques.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve centrally elastic three column layout with header and footer like this if that is what you mean?

With html:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

And css:

```
#top,#bottom{
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
  background:silver;
  clear:both;
}
#middle{
  background:green;
}
#middle,#left,#right{
  height: 200px;
}
#left,#right{
  width: 200px;
  background:skyblue;
}
#left{
  float:left;
}
#right{
  float:right;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hkrVz/

Comment: hmmm.. does he know what will happen to the sides when the center grows beyond 200px I wonder?

Comment: Does he know how to fix it..? How would you fix it? You could put a stretched transparent pixel image at the top... but we stopped doing that right? We could use `min-width:200px` on the top div, but is that going to work in all browsers..? We could add some javascript that detects window size and re-sizes accordingly... or something else? What would you do?

Comment: My solution...put them all inside another div and give that new (lets call it outer) div a height of 100%..works for me...oooh no it doesnt!! @Billy Moon @SpliFF

Answer (score 1):

You can build any table-like structure using divs and `display:table`,`display:table-row`,`display:table-cell` and you won't be abusing table semantics in markup. It really depends if you need to support IE7 as I think these CSS properties were only introduced to IE8 (years after everyone else had them).

If that's going to be a problem then just look around for options with flexibility to do what you need. I can't really think why hardcoded margins would even be an issue so perhaps you need to explain what you are attempting in more detail.

Comment: One of the big downsides to `display: table-*;` is that you can't achieve functionality similar to `colspan` or `rowspan`.